# Upgrade to 20.04: weird cursor trail only on desktop backgroud

Tags: xps, 20.04

That's the case when it's better to show than to write:
[image]
This is only happening on desktop background. Once I open any window or widget the issue disappears. But if I collapse them and move around desktop, it's the same thing again.

Answer (score 1):

Yesterday I was sudddenly confronted with the same phenomenon. I later realized that it started after I experimented with the keyboard shortcut for "zooming". Alt+Super+8 (on some keyboards opt+command+8) should solve the problem. It did for me.

Left Alt/Opt + Left Command/Super + 8 (the number, not F8). You can actually toggle this pointer trail on and off using that key combination (only for the desktop background).